# Can't access certain page in Mac OS X Lion

Tags: macos, internet, osx-lion

I can't access http://developers.facebook.com on OS X Lion 10.7.1 in any way.

**Safari:**

> Safari can't open the page because the server unexpectedly dropped the
>   connection

**Chrome:**

> Error 101 (net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET): The connection was reset

**Firefox:**

> The connection was reset. The connection to the server was reset while
>   the page was loading.

The problem might have been caused by DNS/cache and so on, so I tried the following but to no avail:

1. Deleted cache/DNS
2. Created a dummy user account on my Mac
3. Reinstalled the OS (through the Internet and all my settings remain intact)

Do you have any suggestions other than a fresh reinstallation of my Mac?

Answer (score 1):

Try checking your proxy settings from your Network preferences. Or from Safari's Advanced preferences.  I had similar issues and could not connect to Facebook or Yahoo, but everything else was fine.  Clearing cache, history or reboot did not worked.  I changed proxy settings until I had access and then changed back to original settings.  It's working now.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried Renewing DHCP Lease?

> System Preferences > Network > Your Connection > Advanced... > TCP/IP > Renew DHCP Lease

Have you also tried loading the link in Safari?

**Also, if you have a wireless router, try rebooting it.**

A while back I had some similar issues where some sites would just not load, similar "Connection" errors, and I ended up buying a new router.

Comment: thanks for the tip. I tried that renewing DHCP lease to no avail either.

Also, the problem persists regardless of where i connect to the internet: at school, at home... My friend who has an exact Mac (Lion) can access the site without problems. 

It seems clear to me that the problem is on my machine itself, not the network. I just don't know how to fix this...